# How do I archive a repository via Githubs GraphQL API?

Tags: github-api, github-graphql

I found out that you can do this via the REST API, but ideally I want to stick to the GraphQL API in my program. I've been scouring the [API Documentation](https://developer.github.com/v4/) but I am also pretty shaky and new to GraphQL so I can not seem to find a way to mutate the repository and set the archive state.

I only need to archive, no need for un-archive.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible at the moment, but you can request the functionality by creating a new post [here](https://platform.github.community/c/graphql-api) with the tag `schema-request`.